# AWS device farm not detecting Appium testng tests working with prelauch mode in local

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, testng, aws-device-farm

As instructed in documentation i have created the maven clean build of my project which is working fine on local in prelaunch mode but when i upload my zip file to device farm, it runs the build test and teardown only ,My original tests are not runing.

i am using @test and local machine is showing the resuls.

Comment: Are you passing in any desired capabilities in your code through prelaunch?

Comment: can you share your configuration code or if possible share sample code

Comment: Did you find a soluction for that ?